# Choose how to flatten an array (python)

Tags: python, numpy

This is a sample of the array I am dealing with:

```
    records = [[[['   1'], ['   2'], ['   3'], ['   4']]], [[['   red'], ['   blue'], ['   black'], ['   white']]]]
```

I want to end up with a structure like this one:

```
    [['   1','   2','   3','   4'],['   red','   blue','   black','   white']]
```

I've tried the following:

```
    levelOne = [recs for sublist in records for recs in sublist]
    final = [recs for sublist in levelOne for recs in sublist]
```

And what I've got was:

```
    [['   1'], ['   2'], ['   3'], ['   4'], ['   red'], ['  blue'], ['   black'], ['   white']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `itertools.chain.from_iterable` for flattening/chaining. Then it's just a matter of applying to the right nested list level:

```py
import itertools
list(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(rec[0])) for rec in records)

[['   1', '   2', '   3', '   4'],
 ['   red', '   blue', '   black', '   white']]
```

Or as a single list comprehension

```py
[[r[0] for r in rec[0]] for rec in records]

[['   1', '   2', '   3', '   4'],
 ['   red', '   blue', '   black', '   white']]
```

Or if your nested list is a numpy array to begin with, you can use `numpy.reshape`:

```py
np.reshape(np.array(records), (2, 4))

array([['   1', '   2', '   3', '   4'],
       ['   red', '   blue', '   black', '   white']], dtype='<U8')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your records  array is numpy array then remove np.array(records) just put records If you want simple list then remove np.array casting in np.array(list(...))
in res

```
import numpy as np
res=np.array(list(map(lambda x : x.reshape(-1), np.array(records))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.reshape.html#numpy.chararray.reshape):

```
records = np.array(records)
records = records.reshape(2, -1)

print(records)
```

Output:

```
array([['   1', '   2', '   3', '   4'],
       ['   red', '   blue', '   black', '   white']], dtype='<U8')
```